# Subtract 2 different dates with different criteria in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sybase

I have a question based on the below table -

| Cancel | Product ID | Inception Date | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| No | 120 | 12/08/2020 | 02/02/2018 |
| No | 120 | 12/06/2016 | 10/02/2016 |
| No | 120 | 12/02/2017 | 15/01/2021 |
| Yes | 120 | 12/02/2021 | 03/03/2021 |

I would like to subtract dates from 2 different columns -  minimum of Inception Date i.e. 12/06/2016 and Timestamp where the cancel flag is Yes i.e. 03/03/2021 to get the number of days.

So, 12/06/2016 - 03/03/3021.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you!

Edit: The above table is just a snippet and I have a lot more rows in the original table - more than 3000.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, the following statement is an option:

```
SELECT
   ProductID,
   MIN(InceptionDate) AS InceptionDate,
   MAX(CASE WHEN Cancel = 'Yes' THEN [Timestamp] END) AS [Timestamp],
   DATEDIFF(
     day, 
     MIN(InceptionDate), 
     MAX(CASE WHEN Cancel = 'Yes' THEN [Timestamp] END)
   ) AS Difference
FROM (VALUES
   ('No',  120, '2020-08-12', '2018-02-02'),
   ('No',  120, '2016-06-12', '2016-02-10'),
   ('No',  120, '2017-02-12', '2021-01-15'),
   ('Yes', 120, '2021-02-12', '2021-03-03')
) v (Cancel, ProductID, InceptionDate, [Timestamp])
GROUP BY ProductID
```

Result:

| ProductID | InceptionDate | Timestamp | Difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 120 | 2016-06-12 | 2021-03-03 | 1725 |

Comment: @Zhorov- Thank you for your answer. The above table is going to have a lot more rows, in thousands tbh.

Comment: @BrawlX What are the actual values of these rows? Does the table have more than one row with `Cancel=Yes` per `ProductID`?

Comment: The table has only one row with Cancel = Yes per ProductID.

Comment: I would  also like to add Product ID in the output. However, when I'm trying to add it, the values are changing.

Comment: @BrawlX, it's a simple grouping and conditional aggregation. The answer is updated.

Comment: - In the FROM Statement - I'm using an entire table i.e. the Product Table and not just those 4 values. So when I'm grouping, the subtraction is happening based on this - 'Yes', 120, '2021-12-02', '2021-03-03' and not the initial inception date.

Comment: Something like this - 
```SELECT  tp.cancellation_fg, 
  tp.product_no, 
  MIN(tp.pro_incept_date), 
  MIN(CASE WHEN tp.cancellation_fg = 'Y' THEN tp.[timestamp] END) AS [Timestamp],
  DATEDIFF(day, MIN(tp.pro_incept_date), MIN(CASE WHEN tp.cancellation_fg = 'Y' THEN tp.[timestamp] END)) AS [Difference in Days] 
FROM tproduct tp
WHERE tp.product_no = 'TH22012594'
GROUP BY tp.cancellation_fg,tp.product_no```

Comment: @BrawlX, why do you inlcude `tp.cancellation_fg` in the `SELECT`? Remove the `tp.cancellation_fg` column from the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` clauses.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
   with cte AS (
select *,           
       MIN(InceptionDate) OVER(PARTITION BY ProductID) AS MinInceptionDate
from product
)
SELECT *,
       DATEDIFF(dd, MinInceptionDate, timestamp) AS Diff
FROM cte 
WHERE cancel = 'Yes'
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8cf08/15)